# Using IS TRUE sql statement in Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Assuming I have a SQL query:

```
SELECT phone_id, name
 FROM  calls c WHERE (c.user_id = 2241 
 AND c.phone_id IN ("Google Pixel","Samsung") 

 AND (c.name IN ("Alex","John")) OR c.name IS NULL) IS TRUE)
```

Which works fine: `IS TRUE` statement evaluates the `(c.name IN ("Alex","John")) OR c.name IS NULL)` expression into single one.

But the problem is Doctrine doesn't support `IS TRUE` statement and such queries lead to errors.

> How can I achieve the same functionality using Doctrine, but obviously
>   avoiding `IS TRUE` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

And what is the purpose of `is true`?

Why not just write the query as this?

```
SELECT phone_id, name
FROM calls c
WHERE c.user_id = 2241 AND
      c.phone_id IN ('Google Pixel', 'Samsung') AND
      (c.name IN ('Alex', 'John') OR c.name IS NULL)
```

Comment: I agree, truth is the final test in any where clause.